# Is Ubuntu Live the Right Solution for Me?

Tags: iso, custom-distributions, livedvd

I am in charge of imaging many Ubuntu machines on a weekly basis for the company that I work at. Each time I image a machine with 14.04 I have to install certificates so the machines can access our network and additionally install about 10 packages to bind the machine to our domain.

It takes a lot of time to do this and even after scripting the process I still want to be as efficient as possible. I have been investigating the 'Ubuntu Live' procedure but have not been successful the past few weeks.

I have been following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

**- Can anyone give me any insight into the 'Ubuntu Live' process?

 - Has anyone had to install many files/packages into certain
   directories for many machines?

 - How would you go about this
   project?**

Thanks for reading. You guys have been a great resource to me:D

**Update: I found the solution that I was looking for! Remastersys allowed me to put the correct files in the correct location and then clone the entire environment to an iso and image that to any computer!! I followed this guide; http://linuxhalwa.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-create-ubuntu-live-cddvd-using.html**

Comment: What confuses me most is building the chroot...am I supposed to install packages and files in chroot?